# Elegant way to loop in ascending and descending order

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I have the following code that parses HTML text and trims (or strips) the paragraphs that are empty. It's similar to `.strip` on a String object.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)

# repetition that I want to collapse
doc.css('p').each do |p|
  if all_children_are_blank?(p)
    p.remove
  else
    break
  end
end

# repetition that I want to collapse
doc.css('p').reverse_each do |p|
  if all_children_are_blank?(p)
    p.remove
  else
    break
  end
end

doc.to_s.strip
```

Is there a more elegant way to prevent code that I've labelled with comments to be duplicated and adhere to principles of code-reuse?

Here is what I've come up with but I'm not happy with it yet and wanted to see if there is something better:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)

doc.css('p').each do |p|
  if stop(p) then break end
end

doc.css('p').reverse_each do |p|
  if stop(p) then break end
end

doc.to_s.strip

def self.stop(p)
  if all_children_are_blank?(p)
    p.remove
    false
  else
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: What I'm looking for is something like `doc.css('p')(.each and .reverse_each) do |p|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're looking for, you would like a simpler way to iterate over the elements you're looking at, in order to remove blank `p` elements.

Here is a straightforward way to collapse what you've written, without doing a whole lot different:

```
doc.tap do |d|
  [:each, :reverse_each].each do |sym|
    d.css("p").public_send(sym) do |p|
      if blank_children?(p)
        p.remove
      else
        break
      end
    end
  end
end.to_s.strip
```

I have not tested this out, so you might need to tweak it a little.  If this were production code, I would probably decompose it into one or more method calls in order to keep things clear.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
[*doc.css('p'), *doc.css('p').reverse].each do |p|
  if stop(p) then break end
end
```

In this case, the splat operator ("*") expands both lists into one array, with the elements in ascending, then descending order. Then you just iterate over the whole group.

---

Edit: 
This won't work properly because of the `break` statement skipping to the end of everything. So the proper way of doing this, IMHO, would be to assign the block to a variable. And you might as well eliminate the `stop` function since you are eliminating the duplication of code anyway:

```
remover = lambda do |p|
  if all_children_are_blank? p
    p.remove
  else
    break
  end
end

doc.css('p').to_a.each(&remover).reverse_each(&remover)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: to be clear, the splat operator works like this: `[*[1,2,3], *%w[a b c]] ==> [1, 2, 3, "a", "b", "c"]

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting and I didn't know you could merge the two arrays together like this. I think my only problem with this approach is that the `break` is there to stop trimming from the beginning and to move onto trimming from the end. As this combines it, the trim breaks and doesn't continue from the end. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Note: the ordering is important as I don't want to remove `p` in the middle, only at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
puts "removing a top p" until stop(doc.at('p'))
puts "removing a bottom p" until stop(doc.search('p').last)
```

or just:

```
puts "removing a p" until stop(doc.at('p')) && stop(doc.search('p').last)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've replaced it with `true until stop(doc.css('p').first) and stop(doc.css('p').last)` but with this should I be concerned with addition cycles being used due to `doc.css('p')` being constantly executed in the loop. If so, is there a way to mitigate it.

Comment: There's a possible performance impact, but nokogiri is very fast. For me, I wouldn't worry about it. In any case, the question asked for an elegant solution, not a performant one.